# Sitefinity multiple choice widget

Tags: sitefinity

Is there a way for me to create my own multiple choice widget that will display in the forms section . I don’t want to overwrite the built-in view and JavaScript of the Sitefinity multiple choice widget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create your own form field widget, then you can follow the doc article here:
https://www.progress.com/documentation/sitefinity-cms/for-developers-create-new-fields-for-forms-mvc

but modify it to be a multichoice widget.

You can check the source code of the built-in widget here:

https://github.com/Sitefinity/feather-widgets/blob/master/Telerik.Sitefinity.Frontend.Forms/Mvc/Controllers/MultipleChoiceFieldController.cs

Comment: can I see the Designer view?